# layout add line R

Tags: r, layout

In the 4th example of `layout` function, which can be generated by `example(layout)`,
I want to overlay the line plot on the barplot of samples from a normal distriubtion.
I tried `lines()`, `plot(  , add=TRUE)`, but with no luck.
How can I do that? Or do I have to take a different route from using `layout`?

Comment: Can you be more specific, and provide a complete reproducible example? You "tried" `lines` where? How?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
library(TeachingDemos)
x <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, stats::rnorm(50)))
y <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, stats::rnorm(50)))
xhist <- hist(x, breaks=seq(-3,3,0.5), plot=FALSE)
yhist <- hist(y, breaks=seq(-3,3,0.5), plot=FALSE)
top <- max(c(xhist$density, yhist$density))
xrange <- c(-3,3)
yrange <- c(-3,3)
nf <- layout(matrix(c(2,0,1,3),2,2,byrow=TRUE), c(3,1), c(1,3), TRUE)
layout.show(nf)

par(mar=c(3,3,1,1))
plot(x, y, xlim=xrange, ylim=yrange, xlab="", ylab="")
par(mar=c(0,3,1,1))
bx.out <- barplot(xhist$density, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0, top), space=0)
updateusr( bx.out[1:2], 0:1, xhist$mids[1:2], 0:1 )
xdens <- density(x)
lines(xdens$x, xdens$y, col='blue')
par(mar=c(3,0,1,1))
by.out <- barplot(yhist$density, axes=FALSE, xlim=c(0, top), space=0, horiz=TRUE)
updateusr( 0:1, by.out[1:2], 0:1, yhist$mids[1:2] )
ydens <- density(y)
lines(ydens$y, ydens$x, col='blue')
```

Note the change from `counts` to `density` so that the "heights" of the bars will match with the density and the use of `updateusr` from the TeachingDemos package to match the coordinate systems.  Instead of `updateusr` you could also specify `width` and `xlim` to the `barplot` function.

Comment: Oh, it works. Thank you so much! It was my first question on stackoverflow, and I am impressed with the extertise that people have on this forum.